# useContext and useReducer Hooks not working. Error: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to implement Redux concept in React Native using createContext, useReducer and useContext. Below are my code files:

**Store.tsx**

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

export const myContext = createContext();

export default function Store(props) {
  const counter = 0;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    return state + action;
  }, counter);
  return (
    <myContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </myContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, createContext } from            "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import Store, { myContext } from "./components/Store";

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(myContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Text>HEY</Text>
      <Store>
        <Text>Counter: {state}</Text>
        <Button title="Incr" onPress={() => dispatch(1)} />
        <Button title="Decr" onPress={() => dispatch(-1)} />
      </Store>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    marginTop: 100
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why I'm not able to access 'State' in useContex. I get error "**Cannot read property 'state' of undefined**"
Any help please. It would be very helpful if you can give some good explanation too with details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only access a context's value in a child component of the context Provider. In this case, you are calling useContext above where the Provider is rendered, within Store. In these cases, the default value passed to createContext is given. In this case, `createContext()`, no default value was given, so it is undefined. Hence trying to destructure undefined `const { state, dispatch } = useContext(myContext);` results in the error you are seeing.

Just adding an additional child component should make it work. Something like:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, createContext } from            "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import Store, { myContext } from "./components/Store";

export default function AppWrapper(): JSX.Element {
  // Store, renders the provider, so the context will be accessible from App.
  return (
    <Store>
      <App />
    </Store>
  )
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(myContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Text>HEY</Text>
      <Text>Counter: {state}</Text>
      <Button title="Incr" onPress={() => dispatch(1)} />
      <Button title="Decr" onPress={() => dispatch(-1)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    marginTop: 100
  }
});
```